# How to use the pandas 'isin' function to give actual values of the df row instead of a boolean expression?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, isin

I have two dataframes and I'm comparing their columns labeled 'B'. If the value of column B in df2 matches the value of column B in df1, I want to extract the value of column C from df2 and add it to a new column in df1.
Example:

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

Expected Result of df1:

[image]

I've tried the following. I know that this checks if there's a match of column B in both the dataframes - it returns a boolean value of True/False in the 'New' column. Is there a way to extract the *value* indicated under column 'C' when there's a match and add it to the 'New' column in df1 instead of the boolean values?

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

df1['New'] = df2['B'].isin(df1['B'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'h'], 'C':[1, 5, 777, 10, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['k', 'l', 'f', 'j', 'h'], 'C':[0, 9, 555, 15, 1]})
ind = df2[df2['B'].isin(df1['B'])].index
df1.loc[ind, 'new'] = df2.loc[ind, 'C']
```

df2

```
   B    C
0  k    0
1  l    9
2  f  555
3  j   15
4  h    1
```

Output df1

```
   B    C    new
0  a    1    NaN
1  b    5    NaN
2  f  777  555.0
3  d   10    NaN
4  h    3    1.0
```

Here in ind are obtained indexes of rows df2 where there are matches. Further using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), where on the left are the row indices, on the right are the column names.